# Не работают события мышки в html приложении

Tags: вконтакте, html, iframe, javascript

Вообщем то проблема такая. Написал приложение на html, всё отлично работает. Выкладываю вконтакт как iframe приложение и практически все клики мышки игнорируються, в чём может быть проблема?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное разработчики API через DOM перебили события...